# Eigen::Map with vector of vectors

Tags: c++, eigen3

Simple question, but I couldn't find an answer: I have a raw pointer `float* data` and I want to interpret this as a `Eigen::VectorX<Eigen::Vector3<float>>`. Unfortunately, `Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorX<Eigen::Vector3<float>>> v(data, n)` does not work. So, is it possible to obtain a view to an array of Vectors at all?

Comment: The proper type would be `Eigen::Matrix3Xf` and the corresponding map `Eigen::Matrix3Xf::MapType` (typedef to `Map<Matrix...>`). But that's not the exact same interface as a vector of 3d points would have. Is there a particular reason why you avoid the matrix types?

Comment: @Homer512 I just want it to pass it to a method which expects a vector type. I wonder whether simply doing `std::span<Eigen::Vector3<float>> v{ reinterpret_cast<Eigen::Vector<float>*>(data), n };` would be an option. But I guess it is formally not allowed.

Comment: What's the method interface? `function(const Vector3f&)` or `function(const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Vector3f>&)` and could you change it to the second style, see https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html?

Comment: If you have a (Map to a) `Matrix3Xf m`, then `m.colwise()` should behave mostly like a container of `Vector3f` (i.e., it provides `.begin()`, `.end()`, etc. You cannot `push_back` into it, of course.

Comment: @Homer512 Thank you for your suggestion. I've tried to use `Eigen::Matrix3Xf::MapType`, but I'm receiving the compiler error "static_assert failed: 'YOU_TRIED_CALLING_A_VECTOR_METHOD_ON_A_MATRIX'". Do you know why?

Comment: @Homer512 Okay, what I've tried was `Eigen::Matrix3Xf::MapType u{ data, n }`. That yielded the error above. When I'm using `Eigen::Matrix3Xf::MapType u{ data, 3, n }` instead, then it works. However, isn't that strange? What else than 3 should I specify in the second argument?

Comment: @Homer512 Also: Will `m.col(j)` copy the values of the column? I really don't want that indexing produces any computational overhead.

Comment: Regarding the capslock message: If you compile with assertions, it will check that the passed dimension is 3. Helpful with templated code where fixed size type may pop up in places designed for dynamic sized types. Re: `m.col(j)`: Yes, that's just a [block expression](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Block.html) which is a view into the matrix and an optimizing compiler will eliminate all overhead.

Comment: @Homer512 The compiler optimization eliminating the overhead was exactly what I was hoping for. However, I've measured the performance and in comparison to the (unallowed) solution with the `std::span` the computation time has increased by a factor of > 2.5. (I'm compiling with MSVC 2022; release build, of course.)

Comment: I'd be interested to see the exact code for this one